# Application insights - can I disable everything else, but Error logging and Exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I am trying to add error logging to Application Insights on an Asp.Net Core 6 Web Api.

I want to use Application Insights ONLY to log:

- Exceptions
- Logs

I want **ONLY** these 2 features.

I want to disable EVERYTHING else for financial reasons! Our project can not afford to have other telemetry that these 2 things.

If I set all the options from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#using-applicationinsightsserviceoptions) to false, will I stop ALL other telemetry?

Is there anything else from the big package **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore** that can not be disabled through these options?

Comment: Costs are never a good driver for these kind of decisions. AI is quit cheap. You could always set a daily ingestion cap or enable sampling. Don't you want to know about failed dependencies or failed requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative way is to do filtering through [telemetry processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering).

This gives you ultimate control - you can filter out what you don't need at more granular level (for instance, you might filter out verbose level traces).